# How to programmatically add new crontab file without replacing previous one

Tags: cron, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am working on a small home automation project using raspberry pi (OS -Raspbian).

I want to know how to add more than one crontab file using python-crontab module without replacing the previous entries in `crontab -e`?

I want to programatically (without manually going to `crontab -e` and adding the files there) schedule two python scripts - first script executes after every 5 minute and another executes after every 2 min.

I was successfully able to schedule first script using python-crontab module 
but when I scheduled second script, it replaced the first one in `crontab -e`.
So how to schedule the new crontab file without replacing the previous one ?

If there is another way of crontab scheduling please do suggest with an example code :)

Note:- I want to schedule python scripts in crontab using python scripting only not manually adding the files at `crontab -e`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write a script to add entries in cron (without using the text editor via `crontab -e`), it would be something like:

- run `crontab -l` to a temporary file
- check if your latest command is already in the file.  If so, stop.
- append the latest command to the temporary file
- run `crontab` with the temporary file as a parameter, to replace the scheduled commands

For reference:

- [crontab(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)- maintain crontab files for individual users
- [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) - tables for driving cron

Answer (score 0):

Since crontabs are text files after all, why not just append text?

```
with open("/var/spool/cron/crontabs/john", "a") as ctfile:
    ctfile.write("1 0 * * 3 /path/to/newcommand --option")
```

Answer (score -2):

`crontab -e` is actually a file where you list all of your cronjobs.

When you type `crontab -e` you will get list of previous cronjobs and tildas (`~`).

Press the insert button on your keyboard to switch between modes and press enter at the end of your last cronjob.

It will erase the tilda and you can write your new cronjob here.

To exit insert mode press escape and enter `:wq!` to save changes.

Comment: `crontab -e` is not a file, its a command. The behaviour you describe reflects that when the default editor is 'vi' (or a derivative) however many Linux distributions now default to nano as the default editor. Further the OP asked how to make changes "programatically" while you have have described an interactive approach.