# Adding shell scripts to crontab

Tags: shell-script, cron

I'm using the following command to add a script to crontab:

```
sudo echo "*/1 * * * * /home/centos/fecha.sh" | sudo crontab -u centos -
```

However, when I try adding a second script,

```
sudo echo "*/3 * * * * /home/centos/fecha3.sh" | sudo crontab -u centos -
```

crontab will erase the previous one. I have tried different things (e.g. single line or using cat instead of echo) but I cannot figure out to do this in a simple and straightforward fashion.

Comment: Or perhaps [How to programmatically add new crontab file without replacing previous one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241118/100397)

Comment: Or alternatively [How do I add/remove cron jobs by script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363376/100397)